# Am I proving an identity about Maxwell's "Magnetic" Equations correctly?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

Question 3.12(d) of Gravitation (MTW) has me show Maxwell's "magnetic" equations $F_{\alpha \beta , \gamma} + F_{\beta \gamma , \alpha} + F_{\gamma \alpha , \beta} = 0$ can be rewritten as $F_{[\alpha \beta ,\gamma ]} = 0$, where $\mathbf{F}$ is the electromagnetic field tensor.

The way I did it was subtracting an extra copy of the equations with the indices arranged differently:

$$ 0 = \frac{1}{6}\left[ 0 - 0 \right] = \frac{1}{6} \left[\left( F_{\alpha \beta , \gamma} + F_{\beta \gamma , \alpha} + F_{\gamma \alpha , \beta} \right) - \left( F_{\alpha \gamma , \beta} + F_{\gamma \beta , \alpha} + F_{\beta \alpha , \gamma} \right) \right] = F_{[\alpha \beta , \gamma] }$$

But using this method, I can just as easily show these Maxwell's equations can be rewritten in the form $F_{(\alpha \beta , \gamma)} = 0$ :

$$ 0 = \frac{1}{6}\left[ 0 + 0 \right] = \frac{1}{6} \left[\left( F_{\alpha \beta , \gamma} + F_{\beta \gamma , \alpha} + F_{\gamma \alpha , \beta} \right) + \left( F_{\alpha \gamma , \beta} + F_{\gamma \beta , \alpha} + F_{\beta \alpha , \gamma} \right) \right] = F_{(\alpha \beta , \gamma) }$$

Are both identities true? Or am I doing something wrong? (Or both?) I only ask because I'd expect MTW to have listed both identities in this problem, considering they were so similarly (and easily) answered.

Comment: You have shown that the first equation implies the second, but not equivalence. $F_{(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)}$ is trivially zero because of the antisymmetry of $F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second equation is true. In fact, it is trivially true, even without the usage of the Bianchi identities: it simply follows from the anti-symmetry of $F_{\mu\nu}$.

The point here is that both equations can be seen as consequences of the Bianchi identities, but what we typically mean by "show that one equation can be written as some other equation" is that the two equation contain the same information. This is true for $F_{[\alpha\beta,\gamma]}=0$, from which you can derive the Bianchi identities, but not true for $F_{(\alpha\beta,\gamma)}=0$, which is more akin to an equation of the form $0=0$, which, while true, is trivially true.

You've really only shown that
$$F_{\alpha\beta,\gamma} + F_{\beta\gamma,\alpha} + F_{\gamma\alpha,\beta} = 0 \implies F_{[\alpha\beta,\gamma]}=0.$$
To show that the equations are really the same, you also need to show the reverse inclusion. That's where the difference between symmetrization and anti-symmetrization lie.